# Digital Signal processing-Sampled period

Tags: signal, signal-processing, dsp, math

Please can you help me with exam test preparation. I have take the below past year exam paper.

[image]

I want to know if I am on the correct track and my answers are correct.

x(t) = cos(50.pi.t + 30) which is sampled at 50Hz

to find the sampled signal, F= 0.5 X 50 = 25Hz, Since w= 2.pi.f (angular frequency)

Now I took the sampled Frequency F= 25/50 = 1/2
The Period = 1/F and then The Period = 2

Now for he second question, How many full periods of x(t) are required to obtain the sampled period?

I took the Frequency (F= 0.5 X 50 = 25Hz and the P= 1/f= 1/25 = 0.04

the Period is 0.04 and the Period of the above question is 2/0.04 which is 50.

but the answer is not there so from the below.

Please can you help, me.

regards
Kyle.

Comment: Try drawing out the sinusoid and marking the sampled points.

Answer (score 1):

The question 12 says: how many full periods are requiered to optain the **sampled period** and not how many full periods are requiered to optain the **period of the sampled signal**. This last question is what you answered.
**So the solution for the  question 12 is: 0.5**. Becouse the T of the signal is 0,04s and 50Hz (sampled period) period is 0,02s, then 0,02/0,04=0.5.

Comment: Hi Alf, thank you for the answer but I am still a little confused on the 0.02s. Is my answer for question correct? where i got the period to be 2? So i am not understanding how the 0.02s comes from. please help me understand this mind my stupidity. thanks

Comment: Your answer for question 11 is correct, solution is 2 but your answer for question 12 is not correct, solution is 0.5. Regarding your question "So i am not understanding how the 0.02s comes from" here the reason: 50Hz is frequenz (f)of the sampling then to get the sampled period you must proceed with the equation T=1/f then T=1/50=0,02 s.